# How to stop observing liveData in the start of activity lunch?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, mvvm

I have an activity which has a ViewModel and the activity observes a liveData of ViewModel
when I first start the activity, it works but when I return to it again, I need to be just like new but it since it's still observing the liveDatas , it shows me old data. what should I do? (oh and keep in mind that I can't create a new activity )

This is my Activity

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var idEditText: EditText

lateinit var createAccountTextView: TextView


lateinit var loginButton: Button

private lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

private lateinit var loginActivityViewModel: LoginActivityViewModel


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

    userRepository = UserRepository(application)

    loginActivityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(
        this,
        LoginActivityViewModelFactory(userRepository)
    ).get(LoginActivityViewModel::class.java)


    idEditText = findViewById(R.id.idEditText)
    loginButton = findViewById(R.id.enterButton)
    createAccountTextView = findViewById(R.id.createAccountTextView)

    loginButton.setOnClickListener {

        val loginID = idEditText.text.toString()

        loginActivityViewModel.userEntry(loginID)


    }
    createAccountTextView.setOnClickListener {

        val createAccountIntent = Intent(this, CreateAccountActivity::class.java)

        startActivity(createAccountIntent)

        finish()


    }

}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    loginActivityViewModel.idEditTextMutableLiveData.observe(this, Observer {

        idEditText.error = it

    })

    loginActivityViewModel.onSuccessMutableLiveData.observe(this, Observer {

            val mainIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)

            mainIntent.putExtra(loginValue, UserUI(it.username, it.userId.toInt()))

            startActivity(mainIntent)

    })


}
```

}

Comment: Add what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

The point of using Livedata is to get the latest update to a data source. If your data source is persistent it means the data returned will always be the same.

What you need to do is clear the datasource on application/activity start. Then you can populate the data source as you go.

Livedata will always return data as long as the data source has data.

A way around it is to avoid returning a livedata object altogether and just return the object itself.

Comment: I was more or less going to say the same thing. RXJava has options for different types of observers to handle things like this. If you wanted though you could easily just set the initial value you want in the on resume. I dont belive it would be anti-MVVM pattern as UI events can send data to the ViewModel. And returning to the activity is a UI event